# Windows 10 starts programs but application window is hidden

Tags: windows

I am on a vacation and only have a smartphone and laptop with me. The T400 laptop was upgraded to Win 10 final one weekk ago and ran smoothly.
Suddenly all applications I start have no window. All I can see is the start menu and an empty desktop. A thumbnail preview is shown for all applications I launched but I can't see them on screen.
I rebooted and checked if this is an issue with virtual desktops but this does not seem to be the problem.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Does any of  `Alt+Tab` or `Winkey+Tab` or `Winkey+D` or `WINKEY + CTRL + LEFT ARROW` or `WINKEY + ALT + RIGHT ARROW` or `WINKEY + CTRL + F4` keyboard shorcut work? [Windows 10 Tip: Master Multitasking Keyboard Shortcuts](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/4915/windows-10-tip-master-multitasking-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Comment: @JosefZ Those shortcuts show no reaction. It seems that I can create new desktops but they are empty too. Even Ctrl-Alt-Del does show nothing

Answer (score 2):

Obviously Windows changed my active screen to be the second one, but showed a start menu there. I noticed this when I saw that it took a long time until the mouse cursor became visible: it was on the first screen (which was only virtually there and not physically)

I opened the screen settings blindly and chose the 'move' action from the thumbnails context menu. Then I used the cursor right key to move the settings to the visible desktop. There I was able to remove the superfluous display.

So in the end this was a problem that is not specific to Windows 10 and could have happened with any other version too.

Comment: For me, changing the display scaling fixed the problem. It may have to do with the application not supporting that feature correctly or at all.